# AspectJ declare annotation @method doesn't work

Tags: java, aspectj

I have this annotation defined:

```
public @interface MyAspectWeaved { }
```

And this aspect:

```
aspect MyAspect {
   declare @method : * *(..) : @MyAspectWeaved;
   // Other pointcuts and advices which work without issues
   // ...
}
```

I'm basically trying to mark all methods which could have been affected by MyAspect. The rest of the aspect works fine but for some reason no methods are annotated with @MyAspectWeaved. Google searches and rereading the documentation didn't give me any clues. I'm not very familiar with AspectJ so I assume that either I'm missing something obvious or my understanding of declare @method is incorrect. Anyone see what's wrong?

I'm using AspectJ 1.6.12.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the annotation to:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAspectWeaved {
}
```